# Debian + Unknown host google.com using bridge network

Tags: linux, dns, debian, vmware, gateway

I am trying to install Debian Linux based OS in my XP machine using VM Ware and I trying to setup bridge connection to access the network. But I am getting the error

```
"Unknown host google.com".
```

For reference -> ifconfig command gives -> 
[image]

resolve.conf

[image]

Please help me out !! Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you setup the brdige? Are you using `iptables`? How?? Why don't you install a real Debian on your machine??

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Using VM Setting, I have selected Bridge. I dnt have any idea about iptables. Its project requirement that why I have to install Debian as VM.